# Any example of jquery ui icon button with a drop down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, frontend

I want to implement the visuel effect like the image I attached. I m using jquery UI and believe there must be someone did that before. So it there anyone can show me some some exisitng examples of that effect ?

[image: The effect I want to implement]

Jquery Ui button is at http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/icons.html, but there is no further explaination.

Comment: Instead of viewing the external demo page, check the [documentation's example page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#icons) and click "View Source"

Answer (score 0):

Use the button `icons` option defining both primary and secondary inside that option.

In the source code on the page you can see this:

```
.button({
    icons: {
        primary: "ui-icon-gear",
        secondary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
    },
    text: false
});
```

Note the `text: false` option so that no text inside the button will be displayed.  However you will need to put some text inside the `<button>` tags or else it won't have the right hight. `<button>&nbsp;</button>` would work fine.